# Non equi Left outer join in hive workaround

Tags: hive, left-join

How to implement non-equi left outer join in hive involving more than two tables?

Query Used:

```
SELECT cs.SID, ins.ID, a.ID, e.id, i.id, cs.dateId, cs.timeId,cs.SSTRT,cs.SEND,cs.VAL,cs.IND,cs.TYP,cs.DTPE,cs.BCDE, cs.IVAL,cs.ICNT,cs.RDT,cs.REJ 
from cs_item_hive cs 
LEFT outer JOIN installation_hive ins ON  (cs.SID=ins.SN)
LEFT OUTER JOIN account_hive a ON (ins.AID=a.ID AND ins.MDID = a.MDID)
LEFT OUTER JOIN equipment_hive e ON ins.GBLSID=e.GSN
LEFT OUTER JOIN item_hive i ON (cs.BCDE=i.ibc AND ins.MDID = i.MDID AND ins.AID = i.AID)
where cs.SEND >= ins.IDAT AND cs.SEND < ins.RDAT;
```

Issue:

Records that are not matching WHERE condition are **skipped**. [As, Hive does not support non-equi join, where condition is used]

Requirement:

Records that are not matching the condition should have the ins.ID, a.ID, e.id, i.id substituted as **NULL** [as like equi-join].

How to implement something like this in hive:

```
SELECT cs.SID, ins.ID, a.ID, e.id, i.id, cs.dateId, cs.timeId,cs.SSTRT,cs.SEND,cs.VAL,cs.IND,cs.TYP,cs.DTPE,cs.BCDE, cs.IVAL,cs.ICNT,cs.RDT,cs.REJ 
from cs_item_hive cs 
LEFT outer JOIN installation_hive ins ON  (cs.SID=ins.SN AND cs.SEND >= ins.IDAT AND cs.SEND < ins.RDAT)
LEFT OUTER JOIN account_hive a ON (ins.AID=a.ID AND ins.MDID = a.MDID)
LEFT OUTER JOIN equipment_hive e ON ins.GBLSID=e.GSN
LEFT OUTER JOIN item_hive i ON (cs.BCDE=i.ibc AND ins.MDID = i.MDID AND ins.AID = i.AID);
```

Please guide me to resolve this issue.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can come pretty close with:

```
where (cs.SEND >= ins.IDAT AND cs.SEND < ins.RDAT) or
      (ins.IDAT is null)
```

Alternatively, I think you can use two queries, one for matches and one for non-matches.