# Hive: nonequality join not working in hive

Tags: hive

I am having issue hive LEFT OUTER JOIN.

I had al table in sql-server. then used sqoop to migrate all tables on
hive.

This is the original query from sql-server which contains non-equi LEFT
OUTER JOIN. both table have *cartesian data*.

```
SELECT
   vss.company_id,vss.shares_ship_id,vss.seatmap_cd,vss.cabin,vss.seat,
vss.seat_loc_dscr, vss.ep_seat AS EPlus_Seat, vss.ep_win_seat,
vss.ep_asle_seat, vss.ep_mid_seat, vss.em_win_seat,
   vss.em_mid_seat,vss.em_asle_seat,vss.y_win_seat, vss.y_mid_seat,
vss.y_asle_seat, vss.fj_win_seat, vss.fj_mid_seat,
vss.fj_asle_seat,vss.exit_row, vss.bulkhead_row, vss.eff_dt, vss.disc_dt
FROM rvsed11 zz
LEFT OUTER JOIN rvsed22 vss
   ON zz.company_id = vss.company_id
   AND zz.shares_ship_id = vss.shares_ship_id
   AND *zz.report_dt >= vss.eff_dt *
   AND *zz.report_dt < vss.disc_dt*;

As we know that Nonequi joins are not working in hive ( Nonequi joins
working in WHERE clause but we cannot use with LEFT OUTER JOIN).

See below hive query with noon-equi condition moved to where clause.

SELECT
   vss.company_id,vss.shares_ship_id,vss.seatmap_cd,vss.cabin,vss.seat,
vss.seat_loc_dscr, vss.ep_seat AS EPlus_Seat, vss.ep_win_seat,
vss.ep_asle_seat, vss.ep_mid_seat, vss.em_win_seat,
   vss.em_mid_seat,vss.em_asle_seat,vss.y_win_seat, vss.y_mid_seat,
vss.y_asle_seat, vss.fj_win_seat, vss.fj_mid_seat,
vss.fj_asle_seat,vss.exit_row, vss.bulkhead_row, vss.eff_dt, vss.disc_dt
FROM rvsed11 zz
LEFT OUTER JOIN rvsed22 vss
   ON zz.company_id = vss.company_id
   AND zz.shares_ship_id = vss.shares_ship_id

*WHERE zz.report_dt >= vss.eff_dt AND zz.report_dt < vss.disc_dt;*
```

Original query is giving 1162 records on Sql-Server , but this hive query
giving 46240 records.
I tried multiple workaround to get same logic , but didn't get same result
on hive.

Can you please help me on this to identify this issue and get query working
on hive with same result set.

Let me know you need other details.

Comment: 2 questions: Did you run the modified query in SQL Server, just to make sure that it is semantically identical to the original? Are you sure your "date" fields have been converted correctly?

Comment: Yes..I checked but its not working...

Answer (score 1):

Hive does not allow the use of <= or >= in ON statement to compare columns across table.

Here is an excerpt from the Hive [Manual](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Joins):

Version 2.2.0+: Complex expressions in ON clause

Complex expressions in ON clause are supported, starting with Hive 2.2.0 (see HIVE-15211, HIVE-15251). Prior to that, Hive did not support join conditions that are not equality conditions.

In particular, syntax for join conditions was restricted as follows:

```
join_condition:
    ON equality_expression ( AND equality_expression )*
equality_expression:
    expression = expression
```

Also see this as an alternate: [Non equi Left outer join in hive workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34943451/non-equi-left-outer-join-in-hive-workaround?rq=1)